# CSS: How to custom hover as seen on Product Hunt card items

Tags: html, css, web

## The Problem

On Product Hunt, when hovering over a card, it changes the colour to a darker grey. Then, when you reach the comment box, it changes the card back to white, but now changes the comment box to the darker grey (as seen in the image below).

How does the rest of the card return back to its normal colour when you hover over the comment box?

### What I've Tried

As an intro-level CSS and web dev, I initially thought it was the z-index, but it was not. Does anyone have an idea as to how you can do this?

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated

[image: Product Hunt Hovering over Comment Box]

Answer (score 1):

suppose each card element in your html looks like this

```
<div class = "card">
    <img src = "avatar.jpg">
    <h1> Color Palette generator </h1>
    <h3> Generate a random color palette ..... </h3>
    <div class = "comment-box">
        <icon ....
        <span> 13 <span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to do it only using CSS you could try enclosing the element in a div, assigning it relative position to the card and absolute position to the button, and there if you add Z index.

```
.card {
    position : relative    
}
.comment-box {
    position : absolute;
    top : any;
    left : any;
    z-index 99: 
}
.comment-box:hover {
    backgroud : gray;
}
```

Also you could try javascript events.
you could create an event to assign focus class to elements based on user interaction.

in your style sheet you do something like this

```
.focus {
     background: gray;
}
```

and in your js file do something like this

```
let card = document.querySelector('.card')
let c-box = document.querySelector('.comment-box')

card.addEventListener ('mouseover', function () {
    this.classList.add('focus')
})

c-box.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    card.classList.remove('focus')
    this.classList.add('focus')
})
```

now when you hover over the div card, the focus class will be added to it, and when you hover over the comment div, the class will be removed from the div card and added to the comment box.

surely it can be refined and you should use querySelectorAll and aggregate the events with a FOR looping through each element, but I hope I could have helped you

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm in the process of trying to implement this but would you have any advice if I am using React and styledComponents instead of vanilla js?